# Set default focus on first item in grid list

Tags: javascript, enyo

Once a grid is rendered how can I set focus to the first item. I am running into a problem where when the grid is updated (collection changes) then focus is lost for the entire application .

I am using the moonstone library.

```
 { 
    kind: "ameba.DataGridList", name: "gridList", fit: true, spacing: 20, minWidth: 300, minHeight: 270, spotlight : 'container',
    scrollerOptions: 
    { 
       kind: "moon.Scroller", vertical:"scroll", horizontal: "hidden", spotlightPagingControls: true
    }, 
    components: [
       {kind : "custom.GridItemControl", spotlight: true}
   ]
 }
```

Comment: Which version of Enyo are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hightlight()` is a private method for Spotlight which only adds the `spotlight` class but does not do the rest of the Spotlight plumbing. `spot()` is the method you should be using which calls `highlight()` internally.

@ruben-ray-vreeken is correct that DataList defers rendering. The easiest way to spot the first control is to set [`initialFocusIndex`](http://enyojs.com/docs/latest/index.html#/mixin/moon.DataListSpotlightSupport) provided by moon.DataListSpotlightSupport.

http://jsfiddle.net/dcw7rr7r/1/

```
enyo.kind({
    name: 'ex.App',
    classes: 'moon',
    bindings: [
        {from: ".collection", to: ".$.gridList.collection"}
    ],
    components: [
        {name: 'gridList', kind:"moon.DataGridList", classes: 'enyo-fit', initialFocusIndex: 0, components: [
            {kind:"moon.CheckboxItem", bindings: [
                {from:".model.text", to:".content"},
                {from:".model.selected", to: ".checked", oneWay: false}
            ]}
        ]}
    ],
    create: enyo.inherit(function (sup) {
        return function () {
            sup.apply(this, arguments);

            // here, at least, the app starts in pointer mode so spotting the first control
            // isn't apparent (though it would resume from that control upon 5-way action).
            // Turning off pointer mode does the trick.
            enyo.Spotlight.setPointerMode(false);
            this.set("collection", new enyo.Collection(this.generateRecords()));
        };
    }),
    generateRecords: function () {
        var records = [],
            idx     = this.modelIndex || 0;
        for (; records.length < 20; ++idx) {
            var title = (idx % 8 === 0) ? " with long title" : "";
            var subTitle = (idx % 8 === 0) ? "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" : "Subtitle";
            records.push({
                selected: false,
                text: "Item " + idx + title,
                subText: subTitle,
                url: "http://placehold.it/300x300/" + Math.floor(Math.random()*0x1000000).toString(16) + "/ffffff&text=Image " + idx
            });
        }
        // update our internal index so it will always generate unique values
        this.modelIndex = idx;
        return records;
    },
});

new ex.App().renderInto(document.body);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here as I don't use Moonstone, but the plain enyo.Datalist doesn't actually render its list content when the render method is called. Instead the actual rendering task is deferred and executed at a later point by the gridList's delegate.

You might want to dive into the code of the gridList's delegate and check out how it works. You could probably create a custom delegate (by extending the original) and highlight the first child in the reset and/or refresh methods:

```
enyo.Spotlight.highlight(this.$.gridList.childForIndex(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruben's answer adds on to my answer that I posted in the Enyo forums, which I'm including here for the sake of completeness:

Try using

```
enyo.Spotlight.highlight(this.$.gridList.childForIndex(0));
```

I added a rendered() function to the Moonstone DataGridList sample in the Sampler and I found that this works:

```
rendered: function() {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    this.startJob("waitforit", function() {
        enyo.Spotlight.highlight(this.$.gridList.childForIndex(0));
    }, 400);
},
```

It didn't work without the delay.